# How to prevent Xcode from rebuilding a static library when there are no changes in it

Tags: ios, xcode

In my workspace, there are two projects, one is builded as executable type named `forfun.app` and the other is a static lib named `libcalculate.a`, `forfun.app` use the `libcalculate.a` static lib.

By comparing the create-time of the static lib file, I notice that every time I build `forfun.app`, Xcode will rebuild `calculate` and yield `calculatelib.a` even there are no changes in it.

The other thing I noticed is that the create-time of intermediates(for example:*.o) won't change, so *.m in static library project is not re-compiled.

Now My question is how can I prevent from rebuilding the static library while there are no changes in it ?

Comment: I believe that you are using the source code of those static libraries within the same workspace of _forfun.app_ and have set the target dependency on them. Otherwise i don't see any other reason that Xcode will build it again. Please clarify.

Comment: @Gandalf Yes, you're right.

Comment: I am not sure if this can be done directly but i can suggest a workaround. Create another target same as the first one, and remove the target dependency from first target. Now you need to build this new target only when you modify the files in static library project, otherwise you can continue with first as usual. You will always have latest binaries in your app.

Comment: @Gandalf In fact I have made my situation simple, the real situation is I have many dependences projects and they are dependent on each other. When I build my *.app project, all the other project will rebuild too no matter whether really need them to. So I want a automatic way to avoid rebuilding these static libraries when their dependencies have no changes. thank you all the same :)